# Forcing ko.mapping to create an empty array with mapped properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am creating a view model in Knockout from a model in mvc4. I am using the mapping plugin. Current code looks like this.

**First:** I merge the different MVC4 models I need into a single ko viewmodel.

```
var mergedData = $.extend(true, {}, initialEventData,
    { "Tickets": initialTicketData }, { "TimeZones": timeZones }
);
```

**Second:** I add some mapping to add a computed function to my viewmodel.

```
var mapping = {
    'Tickets': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new updatedTicket(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var updatedTicket = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        return "$" + parseFloat(this.Price()).toFixed(2);
    }, this);
}
```

**Finlly:** I apply the bindings.

```
var eventViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(mergedData, mapping);
```

**However:** Sometimes the Tickets model may come back empty. When this happens, the mapping plugin does not create the observable array (obviously). I need to have an empty array with mapped properties created so that I can push new tickets.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a check to the mapping configuration. Check if the data is there in the updatedTicket function and if it's not, manually create an observable array

Answer (score 0):

just make a container viewmodel where you can create your default tickets array...
also in your callback functions, make sure you use a variable referring to "this"

```
   var mapping = {
    'Tickets': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new updatedTicket(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var updatedTicket = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        return "$" + parseFloat(self.Price()).toFixed(2);
    }, this);
}

var viewModel = function ( )  {
    this.Tickets = ko.observableArray([]);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(mergedData, mapping, this);
}

var eventViewModel = new viewModel();
```

Comment: I'd change `this.Tickets` to have a few extra lines.    var viewModel=function(data) {    var data = data || {}, tickets = data.tickets;}    -- stuffed if I know how to format this in markdown!?